# Raspar lista em site com beautifulsoup

Tags: python

Eu preciso raspar em Python uma lista em um site. Apenas a primeira lista
Meu código está assim:

```
import requests

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get("http://www25.senado.leg.br/web/atividade/materias/-/materia/votacao/2363507")

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

lista = soup.find_all('ul' , class_='unstyled')
```

Está raspando todas as listas. Quero raspar a lista de votação da descrição "Votação nominal, em primeiro turno, da PEC nº 55/2016, que altera o Ato das Disposições Constituicionais Transitórias, para instituir o Novo Regime Fiscal, e dá outras providências (Teto dos Gastos Públicos)."

Mas todas as listas tem tag ul e class unstyled
Alguém sabe com diferenciar as listas?

Pesquisei um pouco depois, li esse site: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/

Creio que seja isso:
listas = soup.find_all('ul' , class_='unstyled', limit=2)

Comment: Que dados precisas extrair dessa pág?

Comment: A primeira lista de votação (Votação nominal, em primeiro turno, da PEC nº 55/2016), com os nomes de senadores e como votaram. Com o comando listas = soup.find_all('ul' , class_='unstyled', limit=2) eu consegui. Agora vou fazer comandos para gravar isso em um csv

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cara ja tentou usar Selenium?

```
pip install selenium
brew install phantomjs
```

Codigo que faz a mesma coisa que você precisa.

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
browser.get("http://www25.senado.leg.br/web/atividade/materias/-/materia/votacao/2363507")

list_senadores = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='unstyled']")

print("Primeira coluna")
for lis in list_senadores[0].find_elements_by_css_selector("li"):
    print(lis.text)

print("Segunda coluna")
for lis in list_senadores[1].find_elements_by_css_selector("li"):
    print(lis.text)
```

Comment: Obrigado, não conhecia
O comando "brew install phantomjs" é para instalar o PhantomJS? É necessário instalar algo antes?
No prompt aparece: 'brew' não é reconhecido como um comando interno ou externo, um programa operável ou um arquivo em lotes.

Comment: Consegui aqui, obrigado. Mas antes:
Instalei (http://phantomjs.org/)
E dei o comando de path: 
path_to_phantomjs = '/Users/Reinaldo/Documents/phantomjs-2.1.1-windows/bin/phantomjs'
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path = path_to_phantomjs)

Comment: Então, se voce instalar com o npm, voce não precisa passar o path do phantomjs, mas dessa forma acredito que funciona também! Abraços

Comment: Obrigado. Por favor, mais uma coisa. Estou olhando a documentação (http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html). Eu preciso raspar a primeira lista de votação,  da PEC nº 55/2016, que tem duas colunas de senadores (de 0 a 40 e de 41 a 80)
O comando list_senadores = browser.find_element_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='unstyled']") só raspa de 0 a 40
Você sabe como raspar a segunda coluna?

Comment: @ReinaldoChaves se voce trocar `find_element_by_xpath` por `find_elements_by_xpath` ele pega todos os `ul` com class `unstyled`. E bem simples o selenium. Ou voce busca por um elemento (no caso ai ele pegou o primeiro UL) ou busca todos existentes. Não esqueça de dar um up se isso for util! Obrigado :D

Comment: Obrigado. O primeiro comando fica assim então: list_senadores = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(".//ul[@class='unstyled']")
Mas depois o for deu erro:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-b9c5cbb095f2> in <module>()
----> 1 for s in list_senadores.find_elements_by_css_selector("li"):
      2     print(s.text)

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'find_elements_by_css_selector'

Comment: Creio que era retirar o CSS selector, obrigado: for s in list_senadores:
    print(s.text)
Mas se existir um meio de pegar só as duas primeiras colunas seria mais produtivo. Se não depois vou limpar os dados

Comment: Entao, no caso, quando voce usa o elements para pegar todas as ULs, ele se torna uma lista de ULS. Entao voce terá que fazer um for nas uls e mais um for em cada uma para obter as LIs. No caso, o site do governo é uma bosta, ele criou todas as uls do site com mesmos atributos. Voce tera que identificar qual elemento/atributo diferencia de cada lista. Vou atualizar o codigo para voce trazer apenas as 2 colunas do primeiro bloco de senadores.

Comment: Obrigado! Coloquei aqui: https://github.com/reichaves/plenario_teste/blob/master/teste1.ipynb

Comment: É uma honra! haha abs